# Node.js MongoDB performance implication of calling db.collection(collection).insertOne()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Using the official native [Node.js MongoDB driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/), is there a significant performance overhead or penalty when inserting documents into a collection, by calling:

```
const collection = 'events';

// loop here {
    db.collection(collection).insertOne({ foo: 'bar' });
// }
```

Namely, calling `db.collection(collection)` each insert? It is not clear from the [Db documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Db.html#collection) if `db.collection(collection)` actually makes a request to the MongoDB server or just updates internal variables. If it does make a MongoDB request, then that would be two round trips per insert.

Comment: There will be function call overhead, but no database overhead since the `collection` call doesn't interact with the database itself.